# Distinct values on annotated field ArrayAgg using Django 1.11 and PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to annotate to queryset field containing list of user account uuids interested and not interested in participation in some kind of event. This project uses Django 1.11 and PostgreSQL, so i wanted to annotate this list using ArrayAgg. Sadly this version of Django does not support distinct kwarg on ArrayAgg so list I'm getting back contains duplicated elements.
Things that I have tried:

1. Using properties on model - this works well and results are good, but instead of 2 queries in 10ms it does ~300 queries in 200ms. It's on development DB so it will be much more noticable on production.
2. Implementing my own `ArrayAgg` and `Aggregate` using code from Django 2.0 repo and it works well, I'm getting desired 2 queries, but is there better way so I can evade such "hacky" solution?

I can't update Django to version 2.0

Code example:
It's version with displayed duplicates

models.py

```
import uuid as uuid
from django.db import models


class Account(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)


class MyUser(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class InterestStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    interested = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name='interested')
    not_interested = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name='not_interested')

    @property
    def interested_users_uids(self):
        ids = []
        for user in self.interested.all():
            ids.append(user.account.uuid)
        return ids

    @property
    def not_interested_users_uids(self):
        ids = []
        for user in self.not_interested.all():
            ids.append(user.account.uuid)
        return ids
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
from rest_framework import viewsets

from test_pap.models import InterestStatus
from test_pap.serializers import InterestStatusSerializer


class InterestStatusViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = InterestStatus.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InterestStatusSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        qs = qs.annotate(
            annotated_interested_uids=ArrayAgg('interested__account__uuid'),
            annotated_not_interested_uids=ArrayAgg('not_interested__account__uuid'),
        )
        return qs
```

serializers.py

```
class InterestStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interested_users_uids = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.UUIDField(), source='annotated_interested_uids')
    not_interested_users_uids = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.UUIDField(), source='annotated_not_interested_uids')

    class Meta:
        model = InterestStatus
        fields = [
            'name',
            'interested_users_uids',
            'not_interested_users_uids',
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`StringAgg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg) function to get the distinct uuids and then leverage you serializer to split the string and convert it to list of uuids.

```
class InterestStatusViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = InterestStatus.objects.all()
   serializer_class = InterestStatusSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
      qs = super().get_queryset()
      qs = qs.annotate(
        annotated_interested_uids=StringAgg('interested__account__uuid',',',distinct=True),
        annotated_not_interested_uids=StringAgg('not_interested__account__uuid',',',distinct=True),
    )
    return qs
```

Serializer can be modified as below to get the required output using [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class InterestStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interested_users_uids = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    not_interested_users_uids = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = InterestStatus
        fields = [
            'name',
            'interested_users_uids',
            'not_interested_users_uids',
        ]

    def get_interested_users_uids(self, obj):
        uuids = []
        if obj.get('annotated_interested_uids'):
            uuids = obj.get('annotated_interested_uids').split(',')
        return uuids

    def get_not_interested_users_uids(self, obj):
        uuids = []
        if obj.get('annotated_not_interested_uids'):
            uuids = obj.get('annotated_not_interested_uids').split(',')
        return uuids
```

Comment: So no way of doing it fully on database side and ORM? Because if i have to use SerializerMethodField, then I could just remove duplicates from annotated ArrayAgg in serializer.

Comment: If using the raw query is an option then it can be done fully on the database side or we can override the arrayagg function in django. But we can't achieve the required result from inbuilt functions for version 1.11. And as you mentioned you already tried overriding the inbuilt function, there is nothing wrong in doing that.